# No fetching of instant messages and e-mail after update to Oreo 8.1

Tags: notifications, 8.1-oreo, instant-messaging

I have a Blackberry keyone that got updated last week to android 8.1, and after that update I need to open Whatsapp, Facebook Messenger Lite, GMail and other similar apps manually to receive the messages and e-mails which has been sent to me. I have checked the notification settings multiple times, and they are set to on. Regular text messages seems to work however.

So without knowing more it feels like there is some kind of syncronization problem?

**These are the steps I've taken so far to try to mitigate the issue:**

- I've disabled the battery and data saving features that comes with android, I don't have any third party applications.
- I don't have any notification applications that could interfere
- I've tried using both cellular and wifi to see if there was any difference, which it wasn't
- My whatsapp and messenger notifications are setup properly
- I'm not restricting background data
- I've restarted my phone
- I've checked the native notification settings, all switched to "on"
- Disabled Power Center

**System information:**

- Android version: 8.1
- Security patch level: 1 July 2018
- Build: ABG044

**Update:**

I discovered that while keeping my phone connected to the desktop version of Whatsapp, I'll receive the messages sent to me on Whatsapp.

Comment: Did you check the settings of Blackberry hub?

Comment: I have the hub disabled.

Comment: 1. What version of Android were you on before upgrading to 8.1?
2. When you say "Messenger", do you mean Facebook Messenger?
3. Are SMS etc also affected?

Comment: Looks like this might be a known issue with your particular phone: https://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-keyone-f445/not-getting-push-notifications-1112690/

Comment: Oops, ignore question 3. Just saw you already answered it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this forum thread](https://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-keyone-f445/not-getting-push-notifications-1112690/), this might be a known issue with your particular phone, and it looks like you've already troubleshot it pretty thoroughly.

Here are a few more things you could try if you haven't already:

1. Factory reset the phone
2. Follow all of [WhatsApp's Notification problems troubleshooting steps](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20887936/?category=5245260). There are a few steps in there that you might not have tried yet.

Unfortunately, if all else fails, you might just have to go back to the previous version of Android that didn't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have gone through the WhatsApp's Notification problems troubleshooting steps, but I haven't reset my phone yet. I really don't want to do it as it's such a tedious work removing stock apps etc. But if it's the only way, I guess I'll just have to buckle up and do it.